# Как читать файл в байтах и сохранить в буфер

Tags: c++, файлы

Здравствуйте меня интересует вопрос как я могу прочитать файл например zip архив в байтах и держать его в буфере для дальнейших действий. Как мне лучше это сделать?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Comment: @dim0n Я использовал данный метод и у меня возникли проблемы, например я читаю файл ios::in | ios::binary и с помощью getline() читаю в string buff. Но когда я начинаю записывать файл он у меня поврежден что я сделал не так?

Comment: @UserNameNickName а не нужно читать с помощью getline. Читайте с помощью read, записывайте с помощью write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если уж вы хотите читать файл в память *полностью*, то можно примерно так:

```
vector<char> readFile(const char* name)
{
    vector<char> buf;
    ifstream in(name,ios::binary);
    if (!in.is_open()) return buf;
    auto sz = in.seekg(0,ios::end).tellg();
    buf.resize(sz);
    in.seekg(0,ios::beg).read(buf.data(),sz);
    return buf;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<char> buf = readFile("data");
    ofstream out("out",ios::binary);
    out.write(buf.data(),buf.size());

}
```

Неплохо дописать в функцию проверки корректности выполнения всех операций.
Сравните потом файлы `data` и `out`, должны быть одинаковы...

Comment: Все супер. Но, мне кажется, что лучше переписать функцию readFile так, чтобы вектор символов передавался в нее по ссылке или указателю. А то как-то не по фэншую, имхо.

Comment: @Majestio На вкус и цвет товарищей нет... Мне кажется логичнее мое решение :)

Comment: @ Harry, я это к Бритве Оккама))) Если можно без временных переменных обойтись, значит - нужно)

Comment: @Majestio Моя логика - нет смысла готовить `vector<char>` заранее, если он той же ценой (без лишних копирований etc) будет создан в самой функции. `vector<char> f; readFile("data",f);` мне нравится меньше, чем `auto f = readFile("data");`

Comment: Я не возражаю против минусов. Я только решительно настаиваю не прятаться трусливо за анонимностью, а пояснять, почему минус. *"Дабы дурость каждого видна была"* (с) приписывается Петру I

Comment: Тут это обычное дело, расслабься ... Щя нейтрализуем анонимуса )

Comment: @Harry на всех последних ответах с `const char * argv[]` мои минусы. Вы сказали, что не хотите со мной общаться, поэтому я и не озвучиваю это под каждым ответом. Все ответы отслеживаются, и после исправления ошибок минусы будут сняты

Comment: @ dIm0n, типа нужно `char * const argv[]`? (https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=execv)

Comment: @Majestio либо без параметров, либо с параметрами, эквивалентными `int` и `char*[]`

Comment: А откуда это утверждение?

Comment: @Majestio из стандарта языка и любых доков. Например, отсюда https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: Этот "референс" - не стандарт, это его компиляция. А вот в стандарте (я смотрел N4659 - это черновик C++17) в п.6.6.1 четкого требования нет. Есть "An implementation shall allow both (2.1) — a function of () returning int and
(2.2) — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int". Хорошо, мы не поставим `const` ... в надежде на будущее изменять `argv`?

Comment: @Majestio ну вы же сами написали `pointer to pointer to char`, а здесь в ответе `const char*[]`. Это разные типы. Т.е. такая форма implementation defined => непортабельна. Вообще, уже 3 раз это объясняю, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175584/398802) обсуждение в комментариях было сегодня. Предлагаю продолжить в том чате, если остались вопросы, а не засорять тут комментарии/уведомления участнику

Comment: Чтоб закрыть этот вопрос - Страуструп написал примерно так - что он согласен с моим мнением (что *безопаснее* писать `const char*`), и что `char*` - проблема исторического свойства (*I agree, but it is hard to mess with the ancient past - you don't know who you might hurt. I \*think\* I tried this and failed almost 40 years ago.*). Поскольку формально я получил разрешение делать так, если мой компилятор это позволяет (*You might simply accept both*), так что, признавая стандарт, я из принципа оставляю все как есть, пока мне не покажут хоть один компилятор, который это не примет :)