# Как можно ускорить работу кода?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Задача была такова: есть "таблица умножения" размера n * n, нужно указать какое количество раз встречается в таблице число k.
То что я написал работает, но когда дело доходит до чисел 1e6, то поиск чисел занимает слишком много времени. А нужно укладываться в 0.5 сек, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int num;

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int z = 1; z <= n; z++)
        {
            unsigned long h;
            h = i * z;
            if (h == k)
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << num;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тема в общем тут не раз попадалась. Надо делать один цикл, перебирать числа только до корня из n и проверять, что остаток от деления на это число нулевой. В результат сразу прибавлять 2 кроме той итерации, где i == корень из k

Comment: Дайте-ка url, хочется убедиться, что O(N) достаточно будет...

Comment: @CrazyElf В этом случае проверки до корня из N недостаточно. Нужна проверка до корня из k.

Comment: @Harry конечно, я имел в виду корень из k, описка просто

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Достаточно проверки в один проход -

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    if (k > n*n) { cout << 0 << endl; return 0; }
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if (k%i == 0 && k/i <= n) count++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;

}
```

Ну, наверное, можно и еще ускорить... но что-то мне кажется, что этого O(N) должно хватить.

Ускорение - проверка не до N, а до корня из K с удвоением результата. Цикл при этом выглядит так:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= sqrt(k)+0.5; ++i)
{
    if (k%i == 0 && k/i <= n)
    {
        count+=2;
        if (k/i == i) --count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112781/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-----).

Comment: @Mikhajlo Чтоб закрыть этот вопрос - Страуструп написал примерно так - что он согласен с моим мнением (что *безопаснее* писать `const char*`), и что `char*` - проблема исторического свойства (*I agree, but it is hard to mess with the ancient past - you don't know who you might hurt. I \*think\* I tried this and failed almost 40 years ago.*). Поскольку формально я получил разрешение делать так, если мой компилятор это позволяет (*You might simply accept both*), так что, признавая стандарт, я из принципа оставляю все как есть, пока мне не покажут хоть один компилятор, который это не примет :)

Answer (score 4):

Вместо того, чтобы генерировать всю таблицу, достаточно разложить число `k` на множители всеми способами, например, проверив на делимость `k` на числа от 1 до корня из `k`

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае код имеет сложно квадратичную. Ее очень легко свести к линейной, убрав внутренний цикл. То есть, вместо

```
for (int z = 1; z <= n; z++)
{
  unsigned long h;
  h = i * z;
  if (h == k)
  {
    num++;
  }
}
```

Запишем так

```
if (k % i == 0) {
  int z = k / i;
  if (z <= n) {
      num++;
  }
}
```

Но зачем проверять аж до n, если можно проверять только до корня с n, а потом просто умножить на два? правда нужно отдельно обработать случай, когда h == n*n (это как раз нужно учитывать только раз).

У меня получилось где то так

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt(k); i++)
{
    if (k % i == 0) {
        int z = k / i;
        if (z <= n) {
            num++;
        }
    }
}
num *=2;
int sq = (int)sqrt(n);
if (sq*sq == n) { num--;}
```

Да, этот код выглядит ужасненько, но думаю, он будет не медленнее разложения на множители и последующей игре с ними.

Comment: Упс... Навскидку взятые 235 и 432 у вас дают ответ 14, в то время как правильный - 18... Где именно прокол, я не копался. Впрочем - кажется, не тот случай, когда можно ограничиться корнем из N.

Comment: Нужна проверка до корня из К.

Comment: я потестил первый вариант (там где без корня и оно дает ответ 18).

Comment: О том и спич - тестировать до корня из N мало, надо до корня из K.